# Unmount ntfs drive in bash script in systemd

Tags: command-line, bash, mount, systemd, unmount

I write an systemd class service to backup up my downloads of linux every time it reboots.

In my shell I have a command line for mount `dev/sda5` but I have't any command for unmount that drive. but it unmountes after it do its works. I want `dev/sda5` be mounted after that.

How can I do that?

Comment: I would guess that your systemd service calls a shell script to do the work? Are you open to modifying that shell script to re-mount sda5?

Comment: Yes. It calls a shell. No I just mount `sda5`. Nothing else. @Jeff Schaller